# How to select only not null values when aggregating with first or last in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My data represents a dictionary that receives a bunch of updates and potentially new fields (metadata being added to a post). So something like:

```js
> db.collection.find()
{ _id: ..., 'A': 'apple', 'B': 'banana' },
{ _id: ..., 'A': 'artichoke' },
{ _id: ..., 'B': 'blueberry' },
{ _id: ..., 'C': 'cranberry' }
```

The challenge - I want to find the first (or last) value for each key *ignoring blank values* (i.e. I want some kind of conditional group by that works at a field not document level). (Equivalent to the starting or ending version of the metadata after updates).

The problem is that:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $group: {
    _id: null,
    A: { $last: '$A' },
    B: { $last: '$B' }, 
    C: { $last: '$C' }
  }}
])
```

fills in the blanks with nulls (rather than skipping them in the result), so I get:

```js
{ '_id': ..., 'A': null, 'B': null, 'C': 'cranberry' }
```

when I want:

```js
{ '_id': ..., 'A': 'artichoke', 'B': 'blueberry', 'C': cranberry' }
```

Comment: `$last` does not work like that in general. It means the "last row" found on a grouping boundary, so in your usage where grouping on `null` you are basically getting results from the last document in the collection by natural order. Perhaps you should ask a question explaining what you are trying to achieve rather than present how you think you should solve your problem. There's likely a better way than how you are approaching it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is what you really want, but it does solve the problem you are asking. The aggregation framework cannot really do this, as you are asking for "last results" of different columns from different documents. There is really only one way to do this and it is pretty insane:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "A": { "$push": "$A" },
        "B": { "$push": "$B" },
        "C": { "$push": "$C" }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$A" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "A": { "$last": "$A" },
        "B": { "$last": "$B" },
        "C": { "$last": "$C" }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$B" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "A": { "$last": "$A" },
        "B": { "$last": "$B" },
        "C": { "$last": "$C" }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$C" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "A": { "$last": "$A" },
        "B": { "$last": "$B" },
        "C": { "$last": "$C" }
    }},
])
```

Essentially you compact down the documents pushing all of the found elements into arrays. Then each array is unwound and the [**`$last`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) element is taken from there. You need to do this for each field in order to get the last element of each array, which was the last match for that field.

Not real good and certain to explode the BSON 16MB limit on any meaningful collection.

So what you are really after is looking for a "last seen" value for each field. You could brute force this by iterating the collection and keeping values that are not `null`. You can even do this on the server like this with mapReduce:

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
   function () {
      if (start == 0)
        emit( 1, "A" );

      start++;
      current = this;

      Object.keys(store).forEach(function(key) {
        if ( current.hasOwnProperty(key) )
          store[key] = current[key];
      });

    },
    function(){},
    {
        "scope": { "start": 0, "store": { "A": null, "B": null, "C": null } },
        "finalize": function(){ return store },
        "out": { "inline": 1 }
    }
)
```

That will work as well, but iterating the whole collection is nearly as bad as mashing everything together with aggregate.

What you really want in this case is three queries, ideally in parallel to just get the discreet value last seen for each property:

```js
> db.collection.find({ "A": { "$exists": true } }).sort({ "$natural": -1 }).limit(1)
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54b319cd6997a054ce4d71e7"), "A" : "artichoke" }
> db.collection.find({ "B": { "$exists": true } }).sort({ "$natural": -1 }).limit(1)
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54b319cd6997a054ce4d71e8"), "B" : "blueberry" }
> db.collection.find({ "C": { "$exists": true } }).sort({ "$natural": -1 }).limit(1)
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54b319cd6997a054ce4d71e9"), "C" : "cranberry" }
```

Acutally even better is to create a sparse index on each property and query via [**`$gt`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/) and a blank string. This makes sure an index is used and as a sparse index it will only contain documents where the property is present. You'll need to [`.hint()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.hint/) this, but you still want [**`$natural`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/natural/) ordering for the sort:

```js
db.collection.ensureIndex({ "A": -1 },{ "sparse": 1 })
db.collection.ensureIndex({ "B": -1 },{ "sparse": 1 })
db.collection.ensureIndex({ "C": -1 },{ "sparse": 1 })


> db.collection.find({ "A": { "$gt": "" } }).hint({ "A": -1 }).sort({ "$natural": -1 }).limit(1)
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54b319cd6997a054ce4d71e7"), "A" : "artichoke" }
> db.collection.find({ "B": { "$gt": "" } }).hint({ "B": -1 }).sort({ "$natural": -1 }).limit(1)
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54b319cd6997a054ce4d71e8"), "B" : "blueberry" }
> db.collection.find({ "C": { "$gt": "" } }).hint({ "C": -1 }).sort({ "$natural": -1 }).limit(1)
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54b319cd6997a054ce4d71e9"), "C" : "cranberry" }
```

That's the best way to solve what you are saying here. But as I said, this is how you think you need to solve it. Your real problem likely has another way to approach both storing and querying.

Answer (score 1):

Starting `Mongo 3.6`, for those using `$first` or `$last` as a way to get one value from grouped records (not necessarily the actual first or last), `$group`'s [`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/#mergeobjects-aggregation) can be used as a way to find a non-null value from grouped items:

```
// { "A" : "apple", "B" : "banana" }
// { "A" : "artichoke" }
// { "B" : "blueberry" }
// { "C" : "cranberry" }
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $group: {
      _id: null,
      A: { $mergeObjects: { a: "$A" } },
      B: { $mergeObjects: { b: "$B" } },
      C: { $mergeObjects: { c: "$C" } }
  }}
])
// { _id: null, A: { a: "artichoke" }, B: { b: "blueberry" }, C: { c: "cranberry" } }
```

`$mergeObjects` accumulates an object based on each grouped record. And the thing to note is that `$mergeObjects` will merge in priority values that aren't `null`. But that requires to modify the accumulated field to an object, thus the "awkward" `{ a: "$A" }`.

If the output format isn't exactly what you expect, one can always use an additional `$project` stage.

Answer (score 0):

So I've just thought about how to answer this, but would be interested to hear people's opinions on how right/wrong this is. Based on the reply from @NeilLunn  I guess I'll hit the BSON limit, making his version better for pulling the data, but it's important to my app that I can run this query in one go. (Perhaps my real problem is the data design).

The problem we have is that in the "group by" we pull in a version of A, B, C for every document. So my solution is to tell the aggregation what fields it should pull in by changing (slightly) the original data structure to tell the engine which keys are in each document:

```js
> db.collection.find()
{ _id: ..., 'A': 'apple', 'B': 'banana', 'Keys': ['A', 'B']},
{ _id: ..., 'A': 'artichoke', 'Keys': ['A']},
{ _id: ..., 'B': 'blueberry', 'Keys': ['B']},
{ _id: ..., 'C': 'cranberry', 'Keys': ['C']}
```

Now we can can `$unwind` on `'Keys'` and then group with `'Keys'` as `'_id'`. Thus:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
                          {'$unwind': 'Keys'}, 
                          {'$group': 
                             {'_id': 'Keys', 
                                'A': {'$last': '$A'}, 
                                'B': {'$last': '$B'}, 
                                'C': {'$last': '$C'}
                             }
                           }
                        ])
```

I get back a series of documents with `_id` equal to the key:

```js
{_id: 'A', 'A': 'artichoke', 'B': null, 'C': null}, 
{_id: 'B', 'A': null, 'B': 'blueberry', 'C': null}, 
{_id: 'C', 'A': null, 'B': null, 'C': 'cranberry'}
```

You can then pull the results you want, knowing that the value for key `X` is only valid for the result where _id is `X`.

(Of course the next question is how to reduce this series of documents to one, taking the appropriate field each time)

Comment: I think you missed the overall point that I was making which was the aggregate is not the optimal way to solve this problem, and the plain queries will run rings around the performance here. The one thing that could be optimized there is by indeed adding an array of "Keys" as shown. But instead, place the keys in reverse order with the last element first. Then you can match on the element with a single index rather than three as `Keys.0`. See the [`$position`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/position/) modfier to `$push` for how to add in that order.

Comment: That was that point in that aggregate is not the best performance option for what you want to do. That said, just add another group on `null` for the grouping id value and get the `$max` of each field. Oh and `$Keys` in all instances instead of `Keys`.